# How to use _embed parameter while fetching Posts by Category (Wordpress)?

Tags: json, wordpress

I am fetching all the posts using the `categories=` parameter as follows :

```
https://recipes.turboweb.online/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=2
```

Here the ID of the category is `2`. So, it fetches me all the Posts containing the CategoryId 2., But, this request doesn't fetch the `Comments` and the `AuthorName` and many more required data.

I know by using `_embed` on a normal query, we would get all the data in a single query which saves time and resources. Here is what the query looks like :

```
https://recipes.turboweb.online/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

This is the Output :

[image: Output]

My question is how can I use `_embed` in the parameters while fetching posts by specific CategoryID? In more simple terms, how can I insert the `_embed` parameter in the below query?

```
https://recipes.turboweb.online/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my local test, this request work fine:

http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=104&_embed

[print of the return test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk88v.png)

And to return the comments, you'll need to apply a function in the rest_api_init hook, something like this:

```
add_action ( 'rest_api_init' , 'add_custom_fields_to_api' ) ;

function add_custom_fields_to_api () {
    register_rest_field ( 'post',
        'comments',
        [
            'get_callback' => 'cb_get_comments'
        ]
    );

}

function cb_get_comments( $object ) {
    // get your comments, for example with the function get_comments()
}
```